# MIME E-mail - While loop - Database - Error

Tags: mysql, while-loop, mime

**Resolved: After installing PHPMailer it now works.**

---

I am trying to use MIME E-mail to send out mail to a large number of members.
Seeing that my web-host has limitations on how long a function can run on their server I had to adjust the old functionality. 
This is how I want it to work:

1. Get every member email-address from database table and create a new table with all of these email-addresses.
2. In the new table I also create two attributes called "Sent" and "Error".
3. I am planning to use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on this functionality. So that every row of email-addresses eventually will be set with Sent = True(1) or Error = True (1).

There is only one problem. I tried testing this on 4 email-addresses. When one of them returns error all the following email-addresses get the same error.

Example of error messages:

```
Error: 501 : malformed address: �> may not follow **Probably caused of ÆØÅ**
Error: 501 : domain missing or malformed  **Because @service.com is missing**
```

etc..

Output example:

```
1: Before function. Error value: 
1: After function. Error value: 501 : domain missing or malformed
2012-10-10 20:07:46 : 1: MemberID: 1, Mail:testme
Error: 501 : domain missing or malformed 

2: Before function. Error value: 
2: After function. Error value: 501 : domain missing or malformed
2012-10-10 20:07:46 : 2: MemberID: 2, Mail:testme@gmail.com
Error: 501 : domain missing or malformed 

3: Before function. Error value: 
3: After function. Error value: 501 : domain missing or malformed
2012-10-10 20:07:46 : 3: MemberID: 3, Mail:testme@hotmail.com
Error: 501 : domain missing or malformed*
```

I can't understand why this happens.

```
######################################
### START NEW MAIL FUNCTION   ####
######################################
##############################################
### Deletes table if already exists   ####
##############################################


$dropExistingTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $databaseTableNameContainingMembers";
mysql_query($dropExistingTable) or die(mysql_error());

####################################
### Creating new table  ####
####################################
$queryCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE $databaseTableNameContainingMembers(ID mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Mail TEXT, MailSent BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, Error BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY (ID))";
mysql_query($queryCreateTable) or die(mysql_error());

####################################
### Filling new table   ####
####################################
//Now we fill the new table with all our members (MemberID, Mail, Sendt = 0).

while ($medlem = mysql_fetch_array($query_medlem)) {
    //insert all member mails to new table
    $memberMail = $medlem["Epost"];
    $queryInsertMemberToNewTable = "INSERT INTO $databaseTableNameContainingMembers (`Mail`) VALUES ('" . $memberMail . "')";
    mysql_query($queryInsertMemberToNewTable) or die(mysql_error());
}

######################################
### Sending function      ####
######################################

function sendMail($table, $email_message) {
##########################################
###     Selecting the new table       ####
##########################################
    $querySelectAllMembersThatHasNotAlreadyBeenSentTo = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `MailSent` = 0 AND `Error` = 0";

//Selects all members that havent been sendt mail to yet.

    $allMembersThatHasNotAlreadyBeenSentTo = mysql_query($querySelectAllMembersThatHasNotAlreadyBeenSentTo) or die("Problem with selecting table. <br>" . mysql_error());

    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($allMembersThatHasNotAlreadyBeenSentTo)) {

        $to_address = $row["Mail"];
        $memberId = $row["ID"];

       $email_message->SetEncodedEmailHeader("To", $to_address, ""); 

        $error = "";
        echo $i . ": Before function. Error value: " . $error . "</br></br>";
        $error = $email_message->Send();
        echo $i . ": After function. Error value: " . $error . "</br></br>";
        echo "</br>";

        if (strcmp($error, "") > 0) {
            ##########################################################
            ###      IF ERROR UPDATE MEMBER VARIABLE "Error"      ####
            ##########################################################
            updateErrorToMember($memberId, $table, 1);
            echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " : " . $i . ": MemberID: " . $memberId . ", Mail:" . $to_address . "</br>Error: $error </br></br></br>";
        } else {
            ##################################################################
            ###    IF SENDING SUCCEEDS UPDATE MEMBER VARIABLE "Sent"      ####
            ##################################################################
            updateSentToMember($memberId, $table);
            echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ": " . $i . " :  Message sent to $to_address<br></br>";
        }
        $i++;
    } //while
}//function

######################################
###    End of sending function    ####
######################################
######################################
###     Run sending function      ####
######################################
sendMail($databaseTableNameContainingMembers, $email_message);
```

Comment: I think the issue is in your Email Class. Instead using that Class use the mail() function and test.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.
How should i use the mail() function? Everything is now based on the PHPMailer class. 
Did i misunderstand you?

Comment: advocating using mail() to debug a phpmailer problem is about the same as advocating using a hotwheels toy car to diagnose a ferrari engine problem. mail() provides absolutely no useful diagnostic error reporting.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what may cause this problem? :) @Marc B

Comment: don't know why you're using setencodedheader, when you could simply use ->AddAddress() and ->ClearAddresses()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clearing the `$email_message` object after each send, you are using the same `$email_message` object, just appending new addresses  and sending, if one of those addresses are incorrect you carry on the error to the following recipients.

You could try replacing your following code:

```
$email_message->SetEncodedEmailHeader("To", $to_address, "");
```

for this one:

```
$email_message->ClearAddresses();
$email_message->AddAddress($to_address, $to_address);
```

Comment: I see your point. Tried to change this part but then i got this: 
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method smtp_message_class::ClearAddresses() in mail.php .

Am i using an old version of PHPMailer or do i actually have to define this method in some way?

Comment: You probably have an old version, what version do you have? you should have a similar method in your version..

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing.. I downloaded PHPMailer this week to use it and uploaded it. But i still use mimemail in this project. I will see to that this is changed and come back to you with an update!

Comment: Thanks for the help, after changing to PHPMailer it now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= stripslashes($msg);
$message .= '</body></html>';

if(mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    updateSentToMember($memberId, $table);
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ": " . $i . " :  Message sent to $to_address<br></br>";
}else{
    updateErrorToMember($memberId, $table, 1);
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " : " . $i . ": MemberID: " . $memberId . ", Mail:" . $to_address . "</br>Error: $error </br></br></br>";
}
```

Just try like this PHP mail() Function if its worked well then i can sure that the issue is in phpMailer Class.

Comment: I tried your mail() function. But it didn't work to well. I don't receive any mail. And the new database table changes every row attribute "Sent" to true(1).